# Javascript get different values into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this data. As you can see there are 4 codes and each code has a different value.

Here is the data:

```
{
    "code": {
        "1": 20,
        "2": 1,
        "3": 2,
        "10": 1
    }
}

var totals = []
```

What I need to do is to put these into the totals array so the final result would look like this:

**[20, 1, 2, 1]**

How can I do this?

Comment: You can loop over your object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like this.push every elements of obj.code using `for in` loop.

```js
    var obj = {
        "code": {
            "1": 20,
            "2": 1,
            "3": 2,
            "10": 1
        }
    };
    var code = obj.code;
    var totals = [];
    for(x in code){
    totals.push(code[x]);
    }
console.log(totals);
```

Comment: can anyone explain why downvoted?it is bad habit to downvote on working answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since ES2017, you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```
var obj = {
    "code": {
        "1": 20,
        "2": 1,
        "3": 2,
        "10": 1
    }
};

Object.values(obj.code);
```

If you're using an older version, you can either use a `for` loop as mentioned in Anthony's answer, or use lodash or undesrcore.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) methods.

```js
var data = {
  "code": {
    "1": 20,
    "2": 1,
    "3": 2,
    "10": 1
  }
};

var totals = Object.keys(data.code).map(function(k) {
  return data.code[k];
})

console.log(totals);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) OR [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
var obj = {
  "code": {
    "1": 20,
    "2": 1,
    "3": 2,
    "10": 1
  }
};

var totals = [];

Object.keys(obj.code).forEach(function(key){
  totals.push(obj.code[key]);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(totals));

console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.values(obj.code)));
```

Answer (score 0):

To maintain a stable result, you should sort the keys in advance.

```js
var data = { code: { 1: 20, 2: 1, 3: 2, 10: 1 } },
    result = Object.keys(data.code).sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b;
    }).map(function (k) {
        return data.code[k];
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
  "code": {
    "1": 20,
    "2": 1,
    "3": 2,
    "10": 1
  }
};
var arr = Object.keys(obj.code).map(function (k) { return obj.code[k]; });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through the keys and add the values to an array:

```
var total = [];
for(var key in a.code) {
    total.push(a.code[key]);
}
```

Comment: I suggest adding `if(a.code.hasOwnProperty(key)` before pushing the value, to avoid adding unwanted values.